# Increasing font size and change Icon using KML for Placemark under Google Earth Studio

Tags: kml, google-earth

I am having trouble increasing the size of the Placemark (font size, and icon size), and also using an alternative pushpin to mark the location. Below is a KML file I put together from looking at other examples. However, it does not work. It still only displays Baltimore, with the default yellow push pin, in the default font size - when I upload the file to Google Earth Studio as an overlay. Does anyone have any ideas what is wrong?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">

<Style id="myStyle">
  <IconStyle>
    <scale>1.3</scale>
    <Icon>
      <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/red-stars.png</href>
    </Icon>
  </IconStyle>
</Style>

  <Placemark>
    <name>
        Baltimore
    </name>
    <styleUrl>#myStyle</styleUrl>
    <description>USA City</description>
    <styleUrl>#My_Style</styleUrl>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-76.61218886467867,39.290384098082626</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need two things to change your placemark icon and increase the size of the label text (If I understand your intention correctly).  First, fix your styleUrl reference, and then construct the necessary style tags.

Your current Placemark contains two `<styleURL>` tags, so it's probably using the second one, which references "My_Style", and looks incorrect.  You can probably fix it by removing the second `<styleUrl>#My_Style</styleUrl>` tag, leaving just the first one: `<styleUrl>#myStyle</styleUrl>`, which references your style: `<Style id="myStyle">...`

Now, to adjust your styles, as you probably know, you can adjust the Icon size by changing the number in the `<IconStyle><scale>1.3</scale>...` tag. Scale "1.0" will be about normal size, scale "5.0" will be huge, something between 1.0 and 2.0 is usually good.

To adjust the text size on the label, you'll need to add a `<LabelStyle>` section to your `<Style>` section.  It would end up looking something like this:

```
<Style id="myStyle">
  <IconStyle>
    ...
  </IconStyle>
  <LabelStyle>
    <scale>1.5</scale>
  </LabelStyle>
</Style>
```

For full documentation on all the sub-sections that can be included in your `<Style>`, see the KML Reference here:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#style